# Simple classification using scikit-learn not working

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

This is the code that I used to solve a classification problem pertaining to credit card fraud detection:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\SVISHWANATH\Downloads\creditcard.csv')
f = df.drop(['Class'], axis = 1)
g = df.Class
g.values.reshape(-1,1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(f, g, stratify = g)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn.predict(y_test)
```

For some reason, even if I specify the reshape parameter, the above code is resulting in an error. This is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-d24a7d3e9bd3> in <module>
     12 knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
     13 knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
---> 14 knn.predict(y_test)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py in predict(self, X)
    171             Class labels for each data sample.
    172         """
--> 173         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    174 
    175         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    622                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    623                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 624                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    625 
    626         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

y_test are the results you're trying to predict (i.e. classes). You need to predict from the available data, i.e. data you would have when trying to classify, which would be everything else except the classes: in your case that is X_test, so you need to change `knn.predict(y_test)` to  `knn.predict(X_test)`. You can then use y_test to compare your predictions and see how accurate they are.

Comment: Thanks! So you would give in the data that you want to predict from, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Imagine if you didn't have a X_test and y_test, and wanted to use your model to classify some data. You might have data similar to X_test, but since what you want to do is get classes, you would not have class information (which is what y_test is). So you predict from information you have, which is similar to X_test (or X_train).